# Upload fora do Lugar

Tags: php, upload

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom estou meio confuso aqui pois estou criando a pasta porem na hora de upar ela upa um nivel acima. onde esta o erro ?

```
 if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"])) {
mkdir("../img/$Npasta") or die("erro ao criar diretório $Npasta");
$foto = time() . '_' . $_FILES["foto"]["name"];
$diretorio = '../img/$Npasta';
$dirfoto = $diretorio.$foto;

if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"], $dirfoto)) {
  $error = TRUE;
 }
}
```

Adendo: Estou criando as pastas dinamicamento pegando o ultimo id do banco somando + 1 e a pasta esta sendo criarda, so nao to entendendo é pq na hora de upar a variavel parece estar "perdida" pois como vcs veem o nome fica $Npasta.taltaltaltal.jpg onde que na verdade teria que ser img/4/nomedoarquivoupado.jpg

Comment: Cola o código normal aqui... porque dessa forma não dá nem pra ler o código

Comment: se clicar na imagem vai aumentar, coloquei imagem pq da pra ver o servidor e como esta sendo upado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim também:

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"])) {
    mkdir("../img/".$Npasta) or die("erro ao criar diretório $Npasta");
        $foto = time() . "_" . $_FILES["foto"]["name"];
        $diretorio = "../img/".$Npasta."/";
        $dirfoto = $diretorio.$foto;

    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"], $dirfoto)) {
        $error = TRUE;
        echo "Imagem não enviada!";
    }
}
```

Comment: no caso estou pegando a imagem via post, e tambem estou usando um subdominio para criacao creio que definir o diretorio assim pode causar algum problema futuro, pois se um dia resolver muda-lo para o dir raiz terei que alterar. de toda forma funcionou a criacao do diretorio , porem a imagem foi para a pasta nivel acima

Comment: deu certo andre, mais aqui me explica ai pq normal $Npasta nao estava pegando e ".$Npasta." assim ja pega?

Comment: Precisa concactenar as variaveis, quando voce for usar só com '', voce pode usar {$var} as chaves substituem o ''